# Conflict between combine and fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, combine

The following simple minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{combine}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\title{Proceedings of the ...}
\author{A. N. Editor\thanks{Support ...}}
\date{29 February, 2000}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{combine} % use the combine page style
\maketitle % main title
\tableofcontents % main ToC
\clearpage
\section{Editor’s introduction} \label{intro} % into main ToC (section 1)
In the article by A.~N.~Author on page~\pageref{art1} ...
\begin{papers} % start of individual articles/papers
\coltoctitle{An article} % first article title into main ToC
\coltocauthor{A.~N.~Author} % first authors into main ToC
\label{art1}
\import{art1} % first article, may have own ToC,
% bibliography, etc.
\coltoctitle{Another article}
\coltocauthor{A.~N.~Other}
\label{art2}
\import{art1}
\end{papers} % end of individual articles/papers
\clearpage
\section{Acknowledgements} % into main ToC (section 2)
Among the many ...
\end{document}
```

taken from the combine package documentation adding the package `fontspec`at the beginning, fails with error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \__driver_color_pickup: already defined.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

anyone could think of a workaround? Are the packages just not compatible?

The same would actually compile in older versions. I have recently updated the whole latex machinery and now this does not work (took me a while to figure out a minimal example).

To compile the above example you need a bogus `art1.tex`, `art2.tex` file, I used:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\title{Organic photovoltaic cells for space applications}
\author{Pippo}
\begin{document}
\label{paper:myname}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
blah1
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
blah2
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is a clash with expl3. The drivers define  the command at `\AtBeginDocument`, but in your case there are two and more `\AtBeginDocument`.  Not difficult to get around it, but I'm not quite sure if combine or expl3 should do it.

Comment: I'll look at this: it's solvable at the `expl3` end ...

Comment: Can I do a workaround myself in the meantime? Or I need to wait for a definite fix upstream?

Comment: Note that also the use of the package `\usepackage[exponent-product = \cdot]{siunitx}` results in the same error (probably for the same reason)

Comment: Any progress @JosephWright?

Comment: @DarioIzzo — frankly I would recommend not trying to use combine. It's pretty awkward and it would be better to add additional markup to your documents to support them being combined. Note you can use the docmute package to "ignore" a preamble.

Comment: The package combine is allowing us a fully automated journal (https://www.esa.int/gsp/ACT/publications/ActaFutura/) pipeline. Not sure there is anything else out there that could achieve the same for us .... Note that Acta Futura is assembled entirely automatically from submitted latex documents having a simple documentclass