# Collection of papers with combine class: incompatibility with latex3/xparse

Tags: latex3, xparse, combine

I'm trying to put together a collection of papers in a single edited volume with the `combine` class. This gives a series of errors, but none fatal, and typesetting is successful. However, some of the papers to be included in my volume use the package `forest`, and this causes a fatal error (TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].), and no typeset.

A minimal example for the master document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{combine}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{combinet} %toc at collection level
\usepackage{forest}

\title{A Collection of Papers}
\author{Collection editors}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{combine}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\begin{papers}
\label{article1}
\import{article1}
\end{papers}

\end{document}
```

And one for the paper that is to be included looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\title{The Noumena}
\author{I. Kant}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\kant[42]

\end{document}
```

As they are given here, the documents fail to typeset. Commenting out the `forest` package in the master document, however, results in a successful typeset.

EDIT: The conflict is due to the fact that `forest` loads `xparse`. Hence, it appears that this is a `combine`/LaTeX 3 incompatibility. See [developer's comments on question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402099/collection-of-papers-with-combine-class-issue-with-forest-package#comment1001703_402099).

Comment: I get the same error, `LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined" Control sequence \__driver_color_pickup: already defined` when trying to load `xparse` (which `forest` uses). So I guess the problem is between LaTeX3 and `combine`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395454/conflict-between-combine-and-fontspec @SašoŽivanović.

Comment: Please leave the added latex3 tags! They were correctly added, then removed and I've now re-added. latex3/xparse is absolutely relevant here.

Comment: Would the docmute package be an alternative solution here? The combine class is rather awkward.

Comment: @WillRobertson `docmute` does not generate a table of contents  at the collection level based on the \title and \author fields of the individual papers, as far as I can see.

Comment: @GuidoVandenWyngaerd Sorry, you're right — you'd need new code to address this sort of functionality. Something half-way between the two packages is needed maybe.